# how to use Spring in a JavaFX application

Tags: java, spring, javafx, fxml

i just started learning spring and try spring with javafx but i'm unable to load fxml. As i check on net there are different ways to load fxml. so, can any buddy help me and i want to know different ways to load a fxml using spring

Main.java

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

     ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        ScreensConfig screens = context.getBean(ScreensConfig.class);
        screens.setPrimaryStage(stage);
        screens.loginDialog().show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

ScreensConfig.java

```
private Stage primaryStage;

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    public void showScreen(Parent screen) {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(screen, 800, 500));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public void loginDialog() {
       setNode(getNode(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"), primaryStage, StageStyle.UNDECORATED));
    }
```

Comment: Just google "JavaFX spring", it will show numerous tutorials and helper libraries to perform this task.  Among those methods, see [Gluon Ignite](http://gluonhq.com/labs/ignite/) or [SpringBoot JavaFX support](https://springboot-javafx-support.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Note, the question is phrased a little weird.  It makes sense to me to ask how to use Spring in a JavaFX application or how to inject Spring Beans into a JavaFX container, but loading FXML doesn't have anything to do with Spring, so it doesn't seem to make sense to ask how to "load fxml using spring".